# Decomposing a subject into simpler grammatical objects

Tags: grammar-identification

> Wild, Fische, und selbst die Tiere in den Staellen erfroren

In this sentence,

The whole subject is: "Wild, Fische, und selbst die Tiere.."

This can be further decomposed into "Wild, Fische, und selbst die Tiere" and "in den Stallen". I identify "in den Stallen" as a prepositional object, but then, what is "Wild, Fische, und selbst die Tiere" supposed to be?

Comment: Your decomposition is wrong. The top-level phrase boundary in that sentence is before *erfroren*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate of your sentence is "erfroren", and the subject is "Wild, Fische, und selbst die Tiere in den Staellen". The subject is an enumeration in three parts: "1. Wild, 2. Fische, 3. selbst die Tiere in den Ställen." Here, "in den Ställen" is an attribute / a modifier to "Tiere" (it says where the animals are). The fish obviously won't be found in a stable, so the "in" must belong more narrowly only to "Tiere".

"In den Ställen" is not called a prepositional object here (which would mean: object of a verb).

Comment: So, is this sentence ungrammatical due to lack of no object?

Comment: A sentence doesn't have to have an object. "I go" is a perfect sentence and has no object either.

Answer (score 1):

> The whole subject is: "Wild, Fische, und selbst die Tiere.."

No - and this seems to be the root of your problem. German (and this has often been said) is a V2-language. That means the *Prädikat* (the inflected part of the *Verb*) goes to second position. (Note, this is true for *Hauptsätze*, main sentences, not *Relativsätze*, relative sentences or *Imperativsätze*, commands.)

This also means that everything going before the *Verb* is *first position* (there is something called *Vorfeld*, but I keep it simple here) - which, in this case, is the *Subjekt* of the sentence.

A *Subjekt* is, in its most basic form, a *Nomen* (noun).

> Der Schirm fehlt. (The umbrella is missing.)

But there can be all sorts of additional parts to the *Subjekt* as long as they are related to the *Nomen* establishing it. Attributes (*Adjektive* or even whole phrases):

> Der rote Schirm fehlt. (The red umbrella is missing.)
> Der von mir in der Garderobe vergessene Schirm fehlt. (The umbrella left by me in the wardrobe is missing.)

But also lists:

> Der Schirm, der Stock und der Hut fehlen. (The umbrella, the walking stick and the hat are missing.)

And, on top, all these can be combined: lists, consisting of elements which have attributes along with them (which themselves could be lists ...):

> Der rote Schirm, der Stock mit dem Silberknauf und der Hut mit dem großen goldenen Abzeichen fehlen.

Here we have a *Subjekt* consisting of a whole phrase (it is fittingly called a *Nominalphrase*):

> Der rote Schirm, der Stock mit dem Silberknauf und der Hut mit dem großen goldenen Abzeichen

The *Subjekt* consists of a list with three elements:

> Schirm
> Stock
> Hut

The first element consists of the *Nomen* along with an attribute defining it more narrowly, the *Adjektiv* "rot".

The second element is basically the same, but here the attribute is not an *Adjektiv* but a phrase itself: "mit dem Silberknauf" (with the silver knob).

The third element is also a *Nomen* with an attribute but in this case the attribute is a phrase itself ("mit dem ... Abzeichen") with a list of attributes ("großen goldenen") in it.

You can add layer upon layer because these structures are recursive. It has been done and it is perfectly possible to overdo it - still grammatically correct but considered bad style.

At last, coming back to your original sentence which you should be able to parse yourself now:

Your *Prädikat* is "erfroren", which is *Plural*, *dritte Person*, *Präteritum*, *Aktiv* - "They froze (to death)." You have a subject consisting of a list (which is why the *Verb* is in *Plural*):

> Wild
> Fische
> Tiere

The first two elements are simple, the last one has an attribute along with it, consisting of a phrase:

> Tiere in den Ställen

Don't be confused by the "selbst", it simply means "even" and just emphasizes. The structure is the same as in English:

> The game, the fish and even the cattle in the stables froze to death.